# ListView GetRect

Tags: listview, winapi

With LVM_GETITEMRECT and LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT I can get the column or row rectangle but I'm looking to get the whole row rectangle plus any area to the right that has no columns up to the scroll bar, how do I achieve this? I have tried GetClientRect then adding on the difference but it always seems to include the width of the scroll bar, this is for drawing alternate background colors across the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the right edge of the rectangle to match the client width is the correct thing to do.  You can use `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL)` to subtract the width of the scrollbar.

Comment: The scrollbar is part of non-client area, i.e. it is already excluded from the client area.